# How do I use Jepack compose to implement a drag sorted list?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement a drag sorted list, functions like drag-sort-recyclerview/gridview,but use jetpack compose.

Comment: What seems to be the issue with it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder LazyColumn items with drag & drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913067/reorder-lazycolumn-items-with-drag-drop)

Comment: look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73592914/9381524

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this library it's help-out
and this is an Example of my usage

```
  implementation("org.burnoutcrew.composereorderable:reorderable:0.6.1")


    val state = rememberReorderState()
val list=notes.toMutableList()
LazyColumn(
    state = state.listState,
    modifier = Modifier.reorderable(state, { a, b -> list.move(a, b) })
) {
    items(list, { it.id }) { noteIndex ->
        Note(
            Modifier
                .draggedItem(state.offsetByKey(noteIndex.id))
                .detectReorderAfterLongPress(state),
            note = noteIndex,
            onNoteClick = onNoteClick,
            onNoteCheckedChange = onNoteCheckedChange
        )
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the library?

Comment: @Harry it is on the first line of the code snippet:
`implementation("org.burnoutcrew.composereorderable:reorderable:0.6.1")`