# How can I Drag-and-Drop list items in the Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement drag and drop list items in the jetpack compose but I want to customize some of the attributes.

**1: Empty text items should not be dragged.**

**2: When we draw a full item, it must go back if the item you want to move is empty.**

How can I create this?

can everyone write this code?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder LazyColumn items with drag & drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913067/reorder-lazycolumn-items-with-drag-drop)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov No, this answer is not clear to me

Comment: look here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/73592914/9381524