# Drag and drop for lazyrow - Jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, row

I was reading this [link](https://proandroiddev.com/basic-drag-n-drop-in-jetpack-compose-a6919ba58ba8)  about drag and drop with lazycolumns. This was written in 2021, I was wondering if there had been any new developments since then and if there were easier implementation available now?
I have also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913067/reorder-lazycolumn-items-with-drag-drop), but it also seems complicated and was written around the same time

Comment: You can checkout this library: https://github.com/aclassen/ComposeReorderable

Answer (score 0):

As of the Compose bom version `implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.01.00')`, it is now natively supported to implement `Modifier.dragAndDropSource` and `Modifier.dragAndDropTarget` on any `Composable` element.

See demo below:

```
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(60.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
                    .dragAndDropSource {
                        detectTapGestures(
                            onLongPress = {
                                startTransfer(
                                    DragAndDropTransferData(
                                        ClipData(
                                            "",
                                            arrayOf("array of mimeTypes - those tell dragAndDropTargets which type of dragAndDropSource this is, such as an image, text, phone number, or your custom type"),
                                            ClipData.Item("you can add new clip items with data here")
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    },
                color = Color.Black,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                text = "Hold me to drag and drop"
            )
            val enteredIndex = remember {
                mutableIntStateOf(-1)
            }

            LazyColumn {
                items(50) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .then(
                                if (enteredIndex.intValue == it) {
                                    Modifier.background(Color.White)
                                } else Modifier.background(Color.Cyan)
                            )
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(80.dp)
                            .dragAndDropTarget(
                                shouldStartDragAndDrop = {
                                    true
                                },
                                target = object : DragAndDropTarget {
                                    override fun onDrop(event: DragAndDropEvent): Boolean {
                                        enteredIndex.intValue = -1
                                        return true
                                    }
                                    override fun onEntered(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                        super.onEntered(event)
                                        enteredIndex.intValue = it
                                    }
                                    override fun onExited(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                        super.onExited(event)
                                        enteredIndex.intValue = -1
                                    }
                                }
                            ),
                        color = Color.Black,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        text = "Content $it, that responds to drag and drop"
                    )
                }
            }
```

Keeping the `MutableState` outside the recycling states of `LazyColumn` items is a safe way of maintaining reference and state. Putting it inside each item causes it to drop the `MutableState` and not respond to the changes of it.

Note that you can drag and drop to other apps as well, see this blog by Google for further reading: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2024/01/whats-new-in-jetpack-compose-january-24-release.html.